# Making a pension calculator to find monthly deposits

Tags: calculator

Im trying to make a pension calculator to find out how much you need to contribute to your pension each month in order to reach your retirement goal.

For instance, let's say you want £250,000 when you retire in 35 years. How much do you have to put away each month (based on a CPI growth of 2.3%).

Comment: Are you expecting to get any interest on the money you put away?

Comment: only 2.3 which is the consumer price index.

If I wanted to add a 2% interest rate then how would I go about this as well?

Comment: May be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74111/pension-calculation